# Excel VBA - Populate Avery Templates

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

looking for some collective brainstorming here, as this will most likely require multiple procedures to accomplish what I envision as the correct approach:

I have the sheet pictures below called “Data” that is populated from a data input sheet named “Entry”.

[Sheets("Data")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQwJF.png)

Note: The reason the Headers & subsequent data “Name/Age/Sex” span over multiple columns (and are merged) is due to the fact of a complex (ie. poor) design layout of the “Entry” page that I have been directed not to alter…

I have the following VBA procedure on a CommandButton that copies the User_Data range from Sheets(“Entry”) to Sheets(Data)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Worksheets("Entry").Range("User_Data").Copy 
Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("A2")
End Sub
```

The end goal here is to populate the information stored in Sheets(“Data”) into a third sheet – Sheets(“Labels”).

[Sheets("Labels")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIFex.png)

This sheet is set up to mimic the dimension of an Avery Label/Sticker Template – 4 stickers per 8.5”x11” page.

I have linked the first Labels data imported via referencing formulas:

```
C6 (Number): ='Data'!A2
C10 (Name):  = ‘Data'!B2
C14 (Age):   = ‘Data'!M2
C18 (Sex):   = ‘Data'!O2
```

How can I use VBA code to create multiple pages of Labels (ie. Copy/Paste/InsertBelow Ranges(“A1:H41”) and auto-populate the User_Data found in  Sheets(“Data”) onto the Labels as required to match however many entries there may be stored within Sheets(“Data”).